# How to redirect and use the framebuffer?

Tags: pipe, framebuffer, streaming

I need to work on the framebuffer to record what is being rendered.

Now, I figure out how to convert the framebuffer in an image, I'm currently unable to obtain a constant stream of data from the fb to create a video.

```
/dev/fb > fb
```

When I do something like this my redirection just drops me and I honestly don't know how to work in another way with the framebuffer.

How I can obtain a stream?

Comment: `/dev/fb` is not a command! Use `cat /dev/fb > fb`

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture data from the framebuffer, you can copy from the framebuffer device file:

`cp /dev/fb0 fb`

If you changed the file you're copying to every time, you should be able to save every frame. Don't expect a lot of Frames per Second though, since the framebuffer is typically pretty slow.

As suggest in [this forum post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/record-using-framebuffer-video-grabber-4175464119/#post4962744), ffmpeg might be a better option:

```
ffmpeg -f fbdev -i /dev/fb0 -r 24 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k output.avi
```

Comment: Why should ffmpeg be faster at reading /dev/fb0 than cat?  Something about that doesn’t make sense (however, I know nothing about ffmpeg).